# Suggestions to learn distributed algorithms involving multi-processes for a beginner

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, distributed-system

I was looking for some book or resource which explains some distributed algorithms involving muti-processes exchanging some data or reading/writing to a shared resource. Not necessarily books, but any other resource (blogs or anythings) which has an explanation and implementation (would be ideal if implementation was in TLA+) of individual algorithms is also fine.

Also, could you suggest to me some rather simple distributed algorithms (again) involving multi-processes to learn and implement for a beginner. I found one - one-bit protocol, could you suggest other algorithms?

Thanks, appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: I'm afraid a question like this will likely be closed because it's opinion-based and this site generally frowns upon similar questions. What's the problem with googling "distributed system programming book"? Do you need academic, or practical engineering resources? From the engineering section, I have good experience with https://dataintensive.net/.

Comment: Yeah, googling gives a lot of options, but I was looking a resource for beginners with nice explanation and probably implementations. Thanks for your suggestion

Comment: Distributed Systems: Principles and Paradigms tanenbaum is a good place to start